# Issue with Show/ Hide text box in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am able to hide the text box on click event of the button and how ca I show the text box on click of same button? That means If text box is showing if I click the button it should hide, If text box is hidden then I click on button it should view. 
How can I do that? the following is my code,

```
<body>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){      
    $("input#btn").click(function(){
      $("input#txt").hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type=text id=txt></input>
<input type=button id=btn value="Click Me"></input>
</body>
```

Any suggestions!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use. jQuery's [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function instead. Change your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $("#txt").toggle();
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/f7JPV/)**

And there's no need to put any selectors in front of the ID since IDs are unique and the extra selector would therefore be superfluous.

Comment: I need the same but by default the text box should be hidden, by on click event it should be shown

Comment: So hide it with CSS (display:none) or $("#txt").hide();

Answer (score 0):

instead of `.hide()` user `.toggle()`. This will solve your problem. Link to jquery api is 
[here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0):

You can animate it too.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){      
    $("input#btn").click(function(){
      $("input#txt").slideToggle('slow',null);
    });
 });
</script>
```